# what can I do to optimize the following function or some other thing to reduce memory consumption?

Tags: php, mysql, memory-management, recursion, query-optimization

I am working on business directory sort of thing, and need to show recursive parents of categories at category listing.

I am using following function for that:

```
    public function get_recursive_parents($category_id){
        $categories = array();
        $res = $this->db->from('categories')->where('cat_id',$category_id)->get()->row_array();
        $cat_id = $res['parent_id'];
        $categories[] = $res;
        while($cat_id){
            $res = $this->db->from('categories')->where('cat_id',$cat_id)->get()->row_array();
            $categories[] = $res;
            $cat_id = $res['parent_id'];
        }
        return $categories;
    }
```

I am using this function and as it is on admin site and a bit slow at admin site can is fine too, and admin will be only one so I can give it more memory.But I think limit memory more than 300M for one call is too much and still getting this:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 367001600 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /var/www/usmanproject/salesfinder/system/database/DB_active_rec.php on line 2007
```

So is there way so that I can optimize above function? or I need to do some specific sort of indexing or algo optimization, or any other possible way? Or I just stop showing all parents and super parents of category (that is client demand to see hierarchy)? Or need to increase memory as I already worked on a directory and that was also slow at admin site so I guess they were just using more Memory?

Any advice will be appreciated.

---

Here is that table schema, it has parent_id so it is working as recursive relation.

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat_desc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat_text` text,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_img` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `last_level` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=221 ;
```

Comment: which framework you are using?

Comment: @ripa I am using CodeIgniter

Comment: ok. you are not calling get_recursive_parents() any time in your function. it's not recursive call.

Comment: @ripa I am doing that recursion work via while loop, I can do that as recursive function but that is not problem problem is of query,this loop will run 4 times maximum and whole function will run no more than 10 times. so at maximum this query can run 40 times on this page while having maximum 1 record at a time. So at max. it can return 40 records but with 40 queries.

Comment: can some sort of stored procedure work better here and solve the issue?

Comment: how many entries do you have in your `categories` table ?

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae right now these are 43 entries, 40 records for one query seems fine but at most 40 queries don't seems fine, thoughts?

Comment: Only 43 entries and the function requires more than 300MB ?

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae yah but queries are in one call in a loop, and these queries can be 40 queries at max, then such memory consumption make sense?

Comment: actually I don't think so, to not abuse of using comments, do you think we can [chat] about this issue ? if yes, we need to fix a time (my timezone is GMT)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24634/discussion-between-abu-romaissae-and-hafiz)

Answer (score 0):

try to use below code

```
public function get_recursive_parents($category_id,$categories=array())
{
    if($category_id!="")
    {
        $new_ar1=array();
        $fe = $this->db->from('categories')->where('cat_id',$category_id)->get()->row_array();
        array_push($new_ar1,$fe["parent_id"]);
        return $new_ar1;
    }
    else
    {
        $res = $this->db->from('categories')->get()->row_array();
        array_push($categories,$res['parent_id']);
        $categories[$res['parent_id']]=array();

        array_push($categories[$res['cat_id']],get_recursive_parents($res['parent_id'],$categories));
    }

    return $new_ar;
}
```

call the function

```
get_recursive_parents($category_id);
```

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved, there was actually a record whose `parent_id` was pointing to its own `cat_id` that is primary key. So that was pointing to itself and in that case that recursion simply wasn't ending. I used while loop and that become infinite in this case.

However during debugging I found this post that was helpful, 
http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ 
It provide better ways to handle same thing. In my scenario self join is useful as mentioned in this post.